# Plotting imaginary and real numbers from an equation

Tags: complex-numbers

I have an equation $y^2=(1+x^2)-\sqrt{1+4x^2}$, how should I plot $y$ vs $x$ (where $y$ has both real and imaginary parts)?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: First, you need to acquire a supply of 3-dimensional graph paper (4-dimensional, if $x$ can also be nonreal).

Comment: thank you. I was trying to plot (3D) using Matlab (i.e., as x, Real(y) and Imaginary(y) )where I found that all the values of y are positive but I should get some 'negative y' value too. Could you please explain?

Comment: What do you mean, "all the values of $y$ are positive"? If $(x,y)$ is a solution, so is $(x,-y)$, so for every solution with positive $y$, there's also a solution with negative $y$. Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it.